# identifying leaves and ancestors of a tree - Python

Tags: python-3.x, tree, networkx

I have a tree as shown below:

[image]

I need to find leaves such that they have the same ancestor. For an example, in the above tree, we have two nodes with the same ancestor. Can someone suggest me a way to do that?

With the help of those two answers, I tried the following to find the pair of leaves with the common parent and then I need to join those two leaves and update the tree. But, that did not give me the correct pair of leaves and did not update the tree correctly. Can you please find the mistake here and help me with that?

```
def common_parent(T, n1, n2):
for n1 in N:
    for n2 in N:
        if T.neighbors(n1) == T.neighbors(n2):
            return (n1, n2)

nodes_pairs = []
for n1 in N:
    for n2 in N:
        if n1 != n2 and common_parent(T, n1,n2):
            nodes_pairs.append(common_ancestor(T, n1,n2))
print(nodes_pairs)

for n1 in N:
        for n2 in N:
            if T.neighbors(n1) == T.neighbors(n2):
                T.add_edge(n1, n2, weight='distance')
print(T.edges())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done like that:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict

G = nx.Graph()

## setup, borrowed from https://necromuralist.github.io/data_science/posts/distance-in-social-networks/
left = tuple("AAKBCCFEDEIE")
right = tuple("KBBCFEGFEIJH")
G.add_edges_from(list(zip(left, right)))
## 

# retrieve nodes of degree=1 
k1corona = list(nx.k_corona(G, 1)) 
# and their parents
nodes = { node: list(G[node])[0]  for _set in k1corona for node in _set }

# counting leaves for each parent
parents = defaultdict(int)
for node,parent in nodes.items():
  parents[parent]+=1

# filtering out loners
leaves = [ node for node,parent in nodes.items() if parents[parent]>=2 ] 

# drawing
pos = nx.spring_layout(G,random_state=0)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G.subgraph(leaves), pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_color='blue')
plt.show()
```

---

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

### Find nodes with a common ancestor

#### create tree

```
G = nx.balanced_tree(2, 2, create_using=None)
```

#### plotting

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos, font_color='w')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: tree]

```
def common_ancestor(G, n1, n2):
    if nx.shortest_path_length(G, n1, n2) == 2:
        return (n1, n2)

nodes_pairs = []
for n1 in G.nodes():
    for n2 in G.nodes():
        if n1 != n2 and common_ancestor(G, n1,n2):
            nodes_pairs.append(common_ancestor(G, n1,n2))
nodes_pairs
```

[out]:

```
[(0, 3),
 (0, 4),
 (0, 5),
 (0, 6),
 (1, 2),
 (2, 1),
 (3, 0),
 (3, 4),
 (4, 0),
 (4, 3),
 (5, 0),
 (5, 6),
 (6, 0),
 (6, 5)]
```